# how to send value in another controller using POST method

Tags: php, yii

I have a scenario in yii. I am using the following code to send some values from one controller to another one as follow :

```
$this->redirect(array('/site/login','hello'=>'hello'));
```

By this method, I can use this value in `sitecontroller` using `$_GET` . Is there any method in yii that I can get this value using `$_POST` method.

If yes then Please share ...

Comment: Are you setting these values or do you want to forward existing `$_POST` values?

Comment: Perhaps just set different action in form?

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why you want to do that?

Comment: because I dont want to show the values to user and i also dont want to send values using a link only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to do such redirect this way.
In Yii and not in Yii.
Find some other solution.